# How to get camera module v2.1 to work on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Tags: pi-4, camera

Not sure what I am doing wrong… camera module v2.1 is connected via ribbon cable.

```
$ cat /boot/firmware/config.txt
gpu_mem=128
start_x=1
```

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0
```

Comment: After enabling legacy camera interface via `raspi-config`, `vcgencmd get_camera` outputs `supported=1 detected=1`. That said, Electron app still doesn’t detect camera.